# How to use the Bootstrap framework in NetBeans?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, netbeans

I recently downloaded the Bootstrap framework from its official website. Currently I'm creating a web application in NetBeans and for designing I want to use this Bootstrap framework I have downloaded.

The Bootstrap package I downloaded contains loads of file but from that I manually added the files like `'jquery.js'`,`'bootstrap.min.css'` etc.

Now I want to use the glyphicons from the Bootstrap, but I have no idea how to integrate the file of glyphicons in NetBeans. So is there a way by which I can integrate the entire Bootstrap package I downloaded in my NetBeans project ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Glyphicon is usually included in the `bootstrap.min.css`
 else you can import them using

**Bootstrap CSS CDN**

`<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

if you want to use them try using them using the syntax

`<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>`

Here is the working [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HLa2S/)

***let me know if it works***

Comment: Thanks it worked. Now is there a way in Netbeans to download the entire bootstrap package?

Comment: what do you mean by package, all you have to do is import the `bootstrap.min.css` & `bootstrap.min.js` in your webpage and you're all set.

Comment: Actually I was worried that eventhough by including bootstrap.min.css glyphicons weren't working, so there might be some other things that might not work. But your link will help me for now, thanks (Y)

Comment: @MAD4RA so that means I am good to go by just substituting/placing bootstrap.min.css/js, css and fonts? No further settings are required?

Answer (score 1):

`Bootstrap` is built into `NetBeans`, no need to download anything except `NetBeans`, as explained here:

https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/up_running_with_twitter_bootstrap

Comment: @geertjanwielanga nice video, but I'am making the application in javaEE and I'am not getting any option for choosing the template.