# can netbeans recognize bootstrap classes just from CDN

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, netbeans

i just started to use Netbeans today, and i noticed when im importing bootstrap from a CDN, netbeans throws errors that he cant find the bootstrap classes. I know i can just link it to my bootstrap folder, but i wanted to know if there is work around  just with a CDN link.

Comment: I guess it's not an error instead it's just a warning. I suggest you to use local bootstrap css files (downloaded) for the development process, later you can put CDN links to your website.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917322/how-to-use-the-bootstrap-framework-in-netbeans) too.

also make sure to select the Site Template correctly

[Site Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMN76.png)

> When you select the No Site Template option the wizard generates a
>   basic empty NetBeans HTML5 project. If you click Finish now the
>   project will only contain a Site Root folder and an index.html file in
>   the Site Root folder. The Site Template page of the wizard enables you
>   to select from a list of popular online templates for HTML5 projects
>   or to specify the location of a .zip archive of a site template. You
>   can type the URL of the .zip archive or click Browse to specify a
>   location on your local system. When you create a project based on a
>   site template the files, libraries and the structure of the project
>   are determined by the template.

Comment: i know, thats not the problem, because the page displays properly since he has access to bootstrap via CDN but, the code editor just is meshed up with hint bulbs that these classes dont exist (since the editor cant acces them i guess somehow)

Comment: Ok, are you sure you select the site template correctly from the beginning ?